# Сортировка массива с частичной радмизацией

Tags: php, массивы, сортировка, случайные-числа

Есть условный массив $mass = ["apple" => "5", "avocado" => "15", "apricot" => "1", "banana" => "5", "plum" => "12", "pineapple" => "5"]

Задача: сделать сортировку по возрастанию + если есть элементы с одинаковыми значениями, рандомить их позицию в массиве при каждой сортировке.

Пытался сделать, но не работает как надо.

```
 usort($mass, function ($a, $b) {
    if ($a == $b) {
    $int = random_int(-1, 1);
    return $int;
    } else {
     return $a < $b ? -1 : 1;
   }
  })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно сначала перемешать массив, а уже потом - сортировать. И для сортировки нужно взять функцию, сохраняющую ключи массива `uasort()`. Пример:

```
$array = [
    "apple" => "5",
    "avocado" => "15",
    "apricot" => "1",
    "banana" => "5",
    "plum" => "12",
    "pineapple" => "5"
];

$keys = array_keys($array);
shuffle($keys);
array_map(function($k)use($array, &$arr){ $arr[$k] = $array[$k]; }, $keys);
uasort($arr, function($a, $b){ return $a <=> $b; });

var_dump($arr);
```